# How to list all hive databases being in use or created so far?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Similar to `SHOW TABLES` command, do we have any such command to list all databases created so far?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[This page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL) mentions the command `SHOW DATABASES`.

From the manual:

```
SHOW (DATABASES|SCHEMAS) [LIKE identifier_with_wildcards];
```

> SHOW DATABASES lists all of the databases defined in the metastore. The optional LIKE clause allows the list of databases to be filtered using a regular expression. Wildcards in the regular expression can only be '' for any character(s) or '|' for a choice. Examples are 'employees', 'emp', 'emp*|*ees', all of which will match the database named 'employees'.

Comment: gotcha! I should have tried before posting it here. It works!! thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

**show databases;**

The above query will list all the databases available in the hive metastore.

Answer (score 0):

For any such queries involving metadata of the objects, you must use the hive metastore deployed on databases such as MySQL or likes of MySQL. You can use the hive database installed on metastore and use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views/tables for your queries

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search database based on wildcards then we can use below commands

show databases like '%<DB_NAME>'

use your database name in place of <DB_NAME>

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better. Also, provide a basic coverage of the content of your link, in case it stops working in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This will work

hive>show databases like 'office*';

It will display all databases whose name start wirh

Answer (score -2):

show databases;

This query should work

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52855712/2227743).