# In Hive, what translates into get_all_databases?

Tags: hadoop, hive

In hive logs, I see a `cmd=get_all_databases` coming from my user.
However, my queries did not request a list of all databases.

I've come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781965/how-to-list-all-hive-databases-being-in-use-or-created-so-far), the answer to which specifies that a `SHOW (DATABASES|SCHEMAS)` query would list all databases, but I did not run such a query.

So what other kind of queries would be translated into `get_all_databases`?

Comment: did you got answer to your question?

Comment: @vbrises Nope...